# How to fix Ubuntu 22.04 Initramfs booting error , harddrive bad sectors, SSD errors?

Tags: boot, 22.04, ssd, initramfs, nvme

I have been using Ubuntu 22.04 in ASUS TUF fx505ge. My laptop is 5 years old.

I have been frequently getting different kinds of "Initramfs errors" and several other errors...

I tried to fix using fsck, and by formatting hdd and SSD and fresh installed Ubuntu in   my SSD.
But the initramfs are still happening...

When I use Ubuntu live with pendrive , it mostly gets stuck after I choose Try or install Ubuntu, at the booting screen...

I couldn't even go into recovery mode.

While I was formatting harddrive, I found it has 2000 bad sectors.

Below I have attached all kinds of errors I have got.

[Pcieport, nvme0 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCgpJ.jpg)

[Currently after doing fresh install Ubuntu, I am facing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A06L6.jpg)

[Error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eptkC.jpg)

[Error 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oikeH.jpg)

I think if I remove my SSD and hdd, and add a new SSD and fresh install Ubuntu , it will work.

Am I thinking correct?

Comment: You can not fix bad sectors. Replace the device.

Comment: Do - **as fast as you can** - backup all of your data and replace the drive.

Comment: @zx485 okay, I will replace the drive asap. So it will fix these issues, right?

Comment: I apologize that I may have been misunderstood: I am **not commanding you** to replace your drive, but rather **recommend you** to do it, because your drive is about to fail _soon_, probably. I do not take any responsibility for your decision, I only advise you to do it in good intention.